# Printing a letter in loop with pagebreak using Java Script

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

My project requirement is to print a letter which is created in Kendo editor and provide in html format. The same letter might be printed for different people as their names come dynamically like we have mail merge field in MS Word.
I am printing on button click using Java script.

I am looping the letter content as below.

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <div style="margin: 100px 10px 10px 50px;" class="print">
        @Html.Raw(item)
    </div>

}
```

Also using the css style to add page break after each letter.
     .print {
        page-break-after: always;
      }

```
.print:last-child {
 page-break-after: auto;
}
```

This letter should be printed on letter head so I put margin top and bottom also.
This works fine when the letter content comes in single page but when letter content is moving into the next page. It is not setting the top margin in next page.

Any Suggestion?

Comment: This is a bit tricky. You'd have to calculate the amount of characters that would overflow into the next page and close the div and open a new one for the second page in order to apply the margins again. 

But the font rendered and the spacing and the zoom will vary on each PC and different browser. 

Have you tried converting the output to a PDF? that way you can work with a format that has page separation and you can control the margins and how the printing works with more detail.

Comment: Yes the amount of character may not work here as the editor has option to change the font size and format and insert image also. the other option to convert into pdf have not tried. That may be the last option I will have..